# How to save MantToMany filed attribute in databse?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making an api in django rest framework. I have created three models in Linkeddata, Individuals group, Event. I have another model Keybase which is another app and have ManyToMany relation with Individual, group and Event. Linked data is in ManyToMany Relation with Individual group and event. While adding data in database,I came to a problem where I dont know How I should save keybase and LinkedData data in Individual, Group and Event table.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from account_management.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from keybase_management.models import Keybase
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
import datetime
from .validators import validate_event_date, validate_expiry_date
# Create your models here.

GENDER = [('male', _('Male')),
          ('female', _('Female')),
          ('other', _('Other'))]


class LinkedData(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    query = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    data = models.JSONField(default={'key': 'value'})


class Portfolio(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, default='')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expire_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
                                     validators=[validate_expiry_date])
    # targets=models.ForeignKey()
    keybase = models.ManyToManyField(Keybase)
    linked_data = models.ManyToManyField(LinkedData)
    addresses = ArrayField(models.CharField(default='null', max_length=225))
    phone_numbers = ArrayField(models.CharField(default='0', max_length=11))
    descriptions = ArrayField(models.CharField(default='null', max_length=225))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_portfolios():
        pass

    def create_portfolio(self):
        pass

    def add_phone_numbers(self):
        pass

    def add_addresses(self):
        pass

    def add_description(self):
        pass


class Individual(Portfolio):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=225)
    religion = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    sect = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)


class Group(Portfolio):
    group_type = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    region = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    details = models.CharField(default='', max_length=500)


class Event(Portfolio):
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
                                      validators=[validate_event_date])
    event_type = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    location = models.CharField(default='', max_length=225)
    event_details = models.CharField(default='', max_length=500)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Individual, Group, Event, LinkedData
from keybase_management.serializers import KeybaseSerializer


class LinkedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LinkedData
        fields = ('type', 'query', 'data')


class IndividualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    key_base = KeybaseSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    linked_data = LinkedDataSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = ('title', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'expire_on', 'key_base', 'linked_data', 'addresses',
                  'phone_numbers', 'descriptions', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'religion', 'sect')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    key_base = KeybaseSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    linked_data = LinkedDataSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('title', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'expire_on', 'key_base', 'linked_data', 'addresses',
                  'phone_numbers', 'descriptions', 'group_type', 'region', 'details')


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    key_base = KeybaseSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    linked_data = LinkedDataSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'expire_on', 'key_base', 'linked_data', 'addresses',
                  'phone_numbers', 'descriptions', 'event_date', 'event_type', 'location', 'event_details')
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, HttpResponse
from .serializers import LinkedDataSerializer, IndividualSerializer, GroupSerializer, EventSerializer
from .models import LinkedData, Individual, Group, Event
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from keybase_management.models import Keybase
# Create your views here.


class PortfolioViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        all_individual_portfolios = Individual.objects.all()
        individual_portfolios_serializer = IndividualSerializer(all_individual_portfolios, many=True)
        all_group_portfolios = Group.objects.all()
        group_portfolio_serializer = GroupSerializer(all_group_portfolios, many=True)
        all_event_portfolios = Event.objects.all()
        event_portfolios_serializer = EventSerializer(all_event_portfolios, many=True)

        all_portfolios = {'individual_portfolios': individual_portfolios_serializer.data,
                          'group_portfolios': group_portfolio_serializer.data,
                          'event_portfolios': event_portfolios_serializer.data}

        return Response(all_portfolios)

    def create(self, request):
        if request.data['individual_portfolios'] is not None:
            for individual_portfolio_data in request.data['individual_portfolios']:
                title = individual_portfolio_data['title']
                created_on = individual_portfolio_data['created_on']
                updated_on = individual_portfolio_data['updated_on']
                expire_on = individual_portfolio_data['expire_on']
                addresses = individual_portfolio_data['addresses']
                phone_numbers = individual_portfolio_data['phone_numbers']
                descriptions = individual_portfolio_data['descriptions']
                date_of_birth = individual_portfolio_data['date_of_birth']
                gender = individual_portfolio_data['gender']
                religion = individual_portfolio_data['religion']
                sect = individual_portfolio_data['sect']

                for individual_linked_data in individual_portfolio_data['linked_data']:
                    type = individual_linked_data['type']
                    query = individual_linked_data['query']
                    data = individual_linked_data['data']

                    LinkedData.objects.create(type=type, query=query, data=data)

                keybase= Keybase.objects.all()
                Individual.objects.create(title=title, created_on=created_on, updated_on=updated_on,
                                          expire_on=expire_on,  addresses=addresses, phone_numbers=phone_numbers,
                                          descriptions=descriptions, date_of_birth=date_of_birth, gender=gender,
                                          religion=religion, sect=sect)

        if request.data['group_portfolios'] is not None:
            for group_portfolio_data in request.data['group_portfolios']:
                title = group_portfolio_data['title']
                created_on = group_portfolio_data['created_on']
                updated_on = group_portfolio_data['updated_on']
                expire_on = group_portfolio_data['expire_on']
                addresses = group_portfolio_data['addresses']
                phone_numbers = group_portfolio_data['phone_numbers']
                descriptions = group_portfolio_data['descriptions']
                group_type = group_portfolio_data['group_type']
                region = group_portfolio_data['region']
                details = group_portfolio_data['details']

                if group_portfolio_data['linked_data'] is not None:
                    for group_linked_data in group_portfolio_data['linked_data']:
                        type = group_linked_data['type']
                        query = group_linked_data['query']
                        data = group_linked_data['data']

                        LinkedData.objects.create(type=type, query=query, data=data)

                keybase = Keybase.objects.all()
                keybase = Keybase.objects.all()
                Individual.keybase.add(keybase)
                Group.objects.create(title=title, created_on=created_on, updated_on=updated_on,
                                     expire_on=expire_on, addresses=addresses, phone_numbers=phone_numbers, descriptions=descriptions,
                                     group_type=group_type, region=region, details=details)



        if request.data['event_portfolios'] is not None:
            for event_portfolio_data in request.data['event_portfolios']:
                title = event_portfolio_data['title']
                created_on = event_portfolio_data['created_on']
                updated_on = event_portfolio_data['updated_on']
                expire_on = event_portfolio_data['expire_on']
                addresses = event_portfolio_data['addresses']
                phone_numbers = event_portfolio_data['phone_numbers']
                descriptions = event_portfolio_data['descriptions']
                event_date = event_portfolio_data['event_date']
                event_type = event_portfolio_data['event_type']
                location = event_portfolio_data['location']
                event_details = event_portfolio_data['event_details']

                if event_portfolio_data['linked_data'] is not None:
                    for event_linked_data in event_portfolio_data['linked_data']:
                        type = event_linked_data['type']
                        query = event_linked_data['query']
                        data = event_linked_data['data']


                        LinkedData.objects.create(type=type, query=query, data=data)


                Event.objects.create(title=title, created_on=created_on, updated_on=updated_on, expire_on=expire_on,
                                     addresses=addresses, phone_numbers=phone_numbers, descriptions=descriptions,
                                     event_date=event_date, event_type=event_type, location=location, event_details=event_details)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PortfolioViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
app_name = 'portfolio_management'

# router = DefaultRouter()
# router.register('/portfolio_viewset', PortfolioViewSet, basename='')

urlpatterns = [
        path('portfolio_list/', PortfolioViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='portfolio_list'),
        path('portfolio_create/', PortfolioViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name='portfolio_create')

]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key_base = KeybaseSerializer(many=True)
linked_data = LinkedDataSerializer(many=True)
```

Don't use read_only=True, can not add data. But when remove read_only=True, you can see form creat data in DRF, don't worry try using postman it's working